# Assigning channels to wires to maximize channel separation and uniqueness

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a system with 79 wires lying parallel to each other that need to be connected to 30 channels (each channel will be connected to 2 or 3 wires). However, it needs to be done in such a way that any two wires on the same channel are not near each other, and do not have wires surrounding them that are on the same channels.  For example, if one wire was on channel 5 and had wires on channels 3 and 4 to its left and wires on channels 6 and 7 to its right, then any other wire on channel 5 needs to be as far away from wires with channels 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 as possible. Essentially, each group of wires around wires on the same channel needs to be as unique as possible.

I wrote a program that assigns channels fairly well, but I was wondering  if there is a method for assigning channels to the wires that will produce an ideal wire layout for maximum channel separation?  Can this be done in general for an arbitrary number of wires and channels?

Comment: Does this question relate to some sort of VLSI chip design?  It sure sounds like it!